# How to manually set angle and length of a nodes handle

Tags: inkscape

When adjusting node handles, I have noticed that at the bottom of the screen it indicates what angle and what length the handle is in relation to the node. Is there a way to manually or directly inputting these values somewhere?

Clarification: I am looking a dialogue where I can key in values for the length and angle for the handle.

Comment: Does https://inkscape.org/doc/keys.html#idm1960 (and following) help? You can change the default step width in Edit > Preferences > Behavior > Steps.

Comment: @moini, I am actually looking for a place that I can key in a value. Those keyboard shortcuts are helpful but, when I work on some projects, it would be nice to just be able to open a dialogue and key in a set of values for the length and angle and move on with the project.

Comment: That dialog doesn't exist currently.

Comment: @Moini - Thanks for the answer. I will quit looking then.